# visibleCells are empty after reloadData/invalidateLayout - how to retrieve the visible cells at the correct time

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I want to access the `visibleCells` in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`, but I get an empty array. The reason is that I called `reloadData` and `invalidateLayout` shortly before in `viewWillLayoutSubviews` and it seems that both functions (`scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` and `viewWillLayoutSubviews`) are asynchronous. Even if want to get the visible cells, right after calling `reloadData` I get an empty array. So it has not been finished recalculating everything.

How do I know at which time/which method there are valid visible cells? Do I have to force everything running on the main UI thread or how do I run that in sync?

**Edit:**

My solution is to use another approach and don't use the visible cells for this.

Comment: It would be great if you post your solution here

Comment: I can't remember what the actual solution was. Perhaps you could hook in which items are requested in the data source or try to work with content offset. Sorry that I can't help you more here.